# Moving a value of object to another but avoid copying

Tags: c++, c++11

There is a scenario where when I get a reply from an API via a callback and I need to move the objects in reply to my class member variable to proceed processing. Will the following code achieve the objective:

```
class Obj {
public:
 Obj (unit32_t& x, std::string& x, int& data)
{}
... lot of variable .. no pointers
};
class A
{
public:
 A(Obj& r):pvtmemVarTyOfObj(0,"",0) {}
 private:
 Obj pvtmemVarTyOfObj ;
};

void A::GetResponse(Obj&& resp)
{
  //pvtmemVarTyOfObj = std::forward<Obj>(std::move(resp));
   pvtmemVarTyOfObj = std::move(resp);

}
```

Will this code actually move resp to pvtmemVarTyOfObj member variable? Just to ensure that no-copy should be done as it will lead to huge processing cost?

Comment: You shouldn't use `move` __and__ `forward`. Use one or the other.

Comment: Thanks - should I remove move or forward to help better processing - note my constructor receives as lvalue - will that be an issue?

Comment: This is up to you. Do you understand the difference between `forward` and `move`? You have to decide whether you want to unconditionally move or only move rvalues. Edit: Haven't even noticed, Obj isn't a templated type, so its not a universal reference... in this case: move.

Comment: I need to move rvalues only and will it not copy cause of '=' operator?

Comment: It will trigger move-assignment. This might still copy, depending on how `Obj` is designed.

Comment: So *is* `Obj` a template parameter? Such pseudoish code is hardly enough of a [mcve] to provide any meaningful answer.

Comment: No Obj has lots of variables only

Comment: showing us the definition of `Obj` might help

Comment: Added the requested details

Comment: What _types_ of variables? If there are no pointers, other dynamic memory resources or non-memory resources then a move is equal to a copy.

Comment: No pointers .. they are POD data types but in many

Comment: moving a POD, is the same as copying it. Some library types, such as `std::vector` can do better, and are specifically designed to do so. The compiler will synthesize move operations for your type, by member-wise move, but if the members are PODs, it will still be the same as a copy

Comment: Yes I agree but I want to move the values

Comment: "Moving" does not physically move anything. Think "transfer the ownership of an object's (indirectly held) resources", not "change the location of an object".

Comment: Will std::swap , std::exchange meet the objective?

Comment: I guess not. You literally can not move data. Its not possible. The __only__ point of move is that you can "steal" ownership of resources to prevent copying even more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The move constructor, and the move assignment operator, only do what they are 
programmed to do, by you the programmer. Technically, they can be designed to
do anything, but that is not advisable.
Rather, they should be designed to make the target object indistinguishable from
the source object, while leaving the source object in a valid state.
If you do not provide a move operation yourself, one will be synthesized by means
of member-wise move.
Move for fundamental types such as `int`, just do a copy.
Move for many library-types, such as `std::vector`, `std::string` and
`std::unique_ptr`, are designed, by the library-implementor, to transfer
ownership of resources, such as memory.
This means, that for a stack-allocated POD, there just is no way to avoid
a copy. If the operation is performance-critical, and a copy is just unacceptable,
the solution could be to not have a stack-allocated POD in the first place, for
example by sticking the object in a `std::unique_ptr`.
Another option could be to only ever have the target object, and let others 'access'
that object through pointers or references.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::move(resp)` here. You know for sure that `resp` is a *rvalue reference*, hence you always want to move.

If `Obj` was a template parameter, you would need to use `std::forward<Obj>(resp)`. Because in this case `Obj&&` would be an *universal reference*, which could be an *rvalue* **or** *lvalue reference* and `std::forward` deduces whether `resp` can be moved from or not.

Whether in the end a copy or move is performed depends on the *assignment operators* of pvtmemVarTyOfObj's class. If it does only contain plain data and no allocated resources (e.g. via pointers), move can't provide any benefits.

Comment: Thanks but will will it not copy cause of '=' operator?

Comment: That depends on class of pvtmemVarTyOfObj. Does it have the [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) overloaded? or just the [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)?

Comment: It has none of them but will compiler invoke or do any costly copy operation when they are not defined?

Comment: Can't tell without more info about pvtmemVarTyOfObj's class

Comment: Consider deleting the copy constructor if you dont need it and are worried about it being invoked

Comment: Will std::swap , std::exchange meet the objective?

Comment: @Programmer Both functions (`swap` and `exchange`) rely on move-construction, move-assigment ...